# MSSQL INSERT INTO woes

Tags: sql, sql-server, vbscript, asp-classic

I am using mssql server 8  /  Classic ASP  with VBscript

I have table called `web_hist`, with the two columns `cust_no` and `item_no`, 
primary key is cust_no + item_no.

The table contains at present about 80000 records

- When a customer places an order on my website his order is stored (TEMPORARILY) in a table called `orders`. This table also contains the fields `cust_no` and `item_no`.
- AFTER the customer checks out, I WOULD LIKE SIMPLY TO INSERT the above 2 fields into the `web_hist` table for each record ordered while skipping any  existing record.

I am looking for an SQL statement I can use to achieve above goal without  producing a 'duplicate key!' error

Comment: I would suggest using an identity column as the primary key.  Your dup key error is most likely caused by duplicate keys in your data.  Your post indicates that the PK on your table is cust_no + item_no? Are you adding those values together ?  Or do you mean cust_no , item_no?  In either case any values that are duplicated in your data set (or which already exist in your table) will cause a dup key error.

Comment: Didi you try anyhing? I yes please show us your trials

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly simple to test if a record with the same `cust_no` and `item_no` exists in the `web_hist` table before inserting the record, but this means that a customer will only be allowed to order any item just once. Seems to me that unless you really want this to happen, you should reconsider your `web_hist` table design.

Should you choose to keep the primary key as is, you should do something like this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM web_hist
    WHERE cust_no = @cust_no
    AND item_no = @item_no
)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO web_hist (cust_no, item_no) VALUES @cust_no, @item_no)
END
/* optional
ELSE
BEGIN
  -- Show a message to the customer that he already ordered this item.
END
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use customer number + item number as primary key as one customer can buy same item more than once.

You can use customer number + order number for the same as a customer will have unique order number for one order.

Comment: Thank  you for   your answers

Comment: Thank you for your answers
Looks like I did not clarify enough

Comment: Excuse me ..I am a newbee in this forum

It looks like i did not clarify enough

table 'web_hist' is just a historical list of all the items a customer has purchase in the past

it used for displaying a customer's history thus allowing him to place an order from a list of his items

we are wholesale distributors and our customers buy every item  repeatedly and quite often

I am sorry for not clarifying that properly

Dory

Comment: In that case you will need to apply check if record already exists or not